# Javascript add line to global variable function from local

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a js files that kept some global function that use in all modul in the application.

Right now I'm working in 1 modul that need to modified that global function from local javascript so every time that function called, the local script also running.

the problem is the global javascript in the other files.js . my Question is how i can manipulate them from my local files when calling the global function

```
$("#btn_save").click(function()
{
alert("This is global function");
// I want insert line here from local javascript
});
```

Thanks,
Hendra

Comment: What is the issue? just place the local javascript there after alert and done.

Comment: I've given an answer, but looking back... what do you mean by "from a local module"? Do you mean from php, or somewhere else in the JavaScript?

Comment: @jai the problem is the global javascript in the other files.js . my Question is how i can manipulate them from my local files when calling the global function.

Comment: @hendrajaya can you explain more about _manipulate_ in what way?

Comment: does your new function requires a modified version of the global function ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing i want to mention that you can bind an event in your case to the the button element and have a check if that button has the id you are looking for. Take a sample below:

```js
// global js
$("#btn_save").click(function() {
  console.log("This is global function");
});

// local js
$("button").click(function() {
  if (this.id === 'btn_save') {
    console.log('local js.');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='btn_save'>Save</button>
<button id='btn_submit'>Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could call an external function from the click event, and change that reference at runtime. Then next time a click happens, that extra function will be called.

```
var other_function;
$("#btn_save").click(function() {
  alert("This is global function");
  if (other_function) { other_function(); }
});

// ...

other_function = function() { alert("This is a local function"); };
```

Comment: If i add that line in my global files, is there any chance affected to other modul that already settle with previous global function? Thanks

Comment: As long as we're talking JavaScript, *not* php, then it will be fine. While `other_function` is not set, nothing different will happen. Once it is set, the extra functionality will kick in.